# Not sure how to clear concurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, 2d-games, concurrentmodification, spawning

Trying to understand why I can't create a new object. I have one spawning object that comes up slowly and once it is done with frame 5 it is supposed to spawn a new object and die. It is throwing a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException and I looked it up but don't understand it. I thought maybe it was calling too many chickens so I did try to create a function to call it from a different class. When called from the other class it made it one line more. It said the string but then got hung on the same exception.

```
@Override
public void die() {
//this is set up to find the last animation frame
float x = location.getX();
float y = location.getY();
int orient = orientation;
    if(animSpawnRight.getIndex() == 4){
        //spawn chicken
        //then die
        handler.getWorld().getChickenSpawner().setHoleFalse(location);

        //executes to here and doesn't read string

        System.out.print("ARG CHICKENS not working!" + x + " , " + y + " , " + orientation);
        handler.getWorld().getEntityManager().addEntity(new Chicken(handler, x, y, orientation));
        super.setActive(false);
    }
}
```

The error log brings me to my Entity Manager:

```
public void tick(){
    Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Entity e = it.next();
        e.tick();
        if(!e.isActive())
             //it.remove() below is the problem
            it.remove();
    }
    entities.sort(renderSorter);
}
```

Goal: ChickenSpawner, which basically watches a timer, spawns a chickenspawning object. ChickenSpawning object plays a short animation and then calls a new chicken. (The spawningChicken and Chicken object were separated because it was easier to make sure you can't shoot it early.

(I even tried commenting out: super.setActive(false); but that didn't work either). Is it calling too many chickens? and If so how do I get it to call only one? I have struggled a bit with multithreading.

**EDIT**
e.tick() calls the classes tick for all "entities" that the entity manager is holding.

And I forgot I put die() in chickenSpawning for some reason - probably a super lazy way to see the chickenspawning animation before finishing how it connected to everything.

```
@Override
public void tick() {
    animSpawnUp.tick();
    animSpawnDown.tick();
    animSpawnLeft.tick();
    animSpawnRight.tick(); 
    die();
}
```

So is it deleting and existing at the same time?

Comment: (1) Post the actual stack trace, not just "is the problem". (2) What is in `e.tick()`? Is it that method itself? Specifically, is it recursive in such a way that you'll have interlocking lists of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

@Joni is correct in his diagnosis.

I can think of two practical approaches to fixing this:

1. Use mutexes to prevent any other threads from accessing or updating the entity list while `tick()` is iterating it.  (And sorting it!)  Note that a CCME when there are multiple threads involved *could be* evidence that you have a larger problems.  If you have multiple threads accessing / updating a shared data structure without adequate synchronization, you can get insidious "memory model" bugs.
2. Use a `CopyOnWriteList` for the list.  It has concurrency properties that ensure that you won't get CCMEs or "memory model" bugs.

@Joni's proposed solution deals with the CCMEs but not the potential "memory model"
bugs.

Finally, if real-time performance is a concern you probably should not be sorting the list on every "tick".  In fact, it might be better to use a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` instead of a list.  (Assuming that the ordering criteria are constant.)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name, `ConcurrentModificationException` most often has nothing to do with multiple threads executing in parallel.

`ConcurrentModificationException` happens for example when you add an item to a list while you are iterating on it. Changing a data structure while you iterate on it may break the iterator state, so it's simply not allowed.

It looks like that's exactly what you are doing: The `tick()` method calls `die()` through some intermediate step. This `die()` method calls `addEntity()`, and `addEntity()` adds an item to the list of entities.

One possible fix is changing `addEntity()` so that it adds items to a *separate list*, and make sure you don't touch the `entities` collection.

You'll also need to change `tick()` so that it adds the new entities from the separate list to the primary `entities` list.

```
List<Entity> recentlyAddedEntities = new ArrayList<>();

public void addEntity(Entity entity) {
    recentlyAddedEntities.add(entity);
}

public void tick(){
    Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
         [.. snip ..]
    }
    entities.addAll(recentlyAddedEntities);
    recentlyAddedEntities.clear();
    entities.sort(renderSorter);
}
```